# How to remove the sub-category from Woocommerce product URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

In permalinks settings the 'Shop Base with Category' `/shop/%product_cat%/` permalink setting puts all the hierarchical categories in the url, for example:

http:// mystore.com/shop/**parent-category**/child-category/**product**

I want to remove anything between parent-category and product so my urls look like:

http:// mystore.com/shop/**parent-category/product**

I am pretty sure that setting up urls like this does not cause problems, because I can manually type the shortened url into an address bar and it goes to the same place as the longer one.

Thanks.

Comment: This is something I have just found too, but it doesn't work if the URL is already in the browser - ie, linked externally. If Google has indexed it with the Sub Category version, can a function strip out the sub-category, and 301 it to the version asked about here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. Use the `woocommerce_product_post_type_link_parent_category_only` filter:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_post_type_link_parent_category_only', '__return_true' );
```

Tried and tested working.

PS: The code would go into the theme functions file and `__return_true()` is a WordPress [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_true/).

Comment: I had been working on custom rewrites.  This works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU. Worked for me after 1,5 weeks tring with plugins, etc,...